# Is it possible to perform XOR operation on 4bytes at a time

Tags: java

i need to perform XOR operation on 4 bytes which are represented as a single byte

```
b[0]=97;
b[1]=98;
b[2]=99;
b[3]=100;
int temp=0;
int temp1=0;
int temp2=0;
int temp3=0;
int temp4=0;
temp1=temp1|b[0];
temp1=temp1<<24;
temp2=temp2|b[1];
temp2=temp2<<16;
temp3=temp3|b[2];
temp3=temp3<<8;
temp4=temp4|b[3];
temp=temp4|temp3|temp2|temp1;
```

i have used the above code to convert the four bytes into a single integer. Now how can i represent this integer in a byte

Comment: without any code I doubt you'll get a better answer than : yes, create a little method that splits your byte in for and tast those 4 with an XOR

Comment: ...huh?  4 bytes represented as a single byte?  You're gonna have to clarify.

Comment: Can't you pack your 4 bytes as an int and XOR it ?

Comment: You can't represent 4 bytes as 1 byte, they won't fit. You also can't represent an integer as a byte, for the same reason. It won't fit. But I'm curious, why can't you simply XOR byte by byte?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming you have 2 byte arrays that you want to XOR
byte[] ba1 = new byte[4];
byte[] ba2 = new byte[4];

// Just filling up with arb. values
ba1[0] = 99;
ba1[1] = 100;
ba1[2] = 101;
ba1[3] = 102;

ba2[0] = 10;
ba2[1] = 11;
ba2[2] = 12;
ba2[3] = 13;

// To store the XOR in ba1 (or new byte[] if you want)
ba1[0] = ba1[0] ^ ba2[0];
ba1[1] = ba1[1] ^ ba2[1];
ba1[2] = ba1[2] ^ ba2[2];
ba1[3] = ba1[3] ^ ba2[3];
```

Now you can convert it to an integer again if you want. But from how I understand your question you actually want them in `byte[]` format.